# What is the difference between passing a function name in onclick react and calling it through callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know the difference between these two statements in react.

```
<Button onClick={this.Callme}></Button>

<Button onClick={()=>this.Callme()}></Button>
```

Its just syntax or is there any difference in functionality too.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the function depends on having a calling context of the instance, and the function isn't bound to the current instance already, the first code won't work, because the `this` inside `callMe` will be `undefined`:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  name = 'component_name';
  Callme() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.Callme}>Click</button>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The second code works, because the `this` in the anonymous arrow function will inherit the `this` from the outer scope, the instance:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  name = 'component_name';
  Callme() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.Callme()}>Click</button>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If the `Callme` method does not need to refer to the instance, then either type of `onClick` works.

Other solutions to this common problem include:

- Binding the method in the constructor (`this.Callme = this.Callme.bind(this)`)
- Binding the method when setting the callback (`onClick={this.Callme.bind(this)}>`)
- Defining the method as an arrow function in the constructor (or as a class field), rather than as a property of the prototype

  ```
  class Component extends React.Component {
    this.Callme = () => {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  ```