# Difference of using parentheses () and not when calling function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parentheses

I have a question regarding calling a function in React.

Say I have this code:

```
function test() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Then I am implementing it like this:

```
        return (
            <TextField label="Name" name='itemName' value={formValues.itemName} onChange={test} />
    )
```

If I do it this way: `test` it will be fine. It will only change when I put something on the field.

But if I do it `test()` then the function will be triggered right away on every render.

Can someone enlighten me more about these differences?
And are there any occassions where I should use the parentheses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between passing a function name in onclick react and calling it through callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428803/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-a-function-name-in-onclick-react-and-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `test()` you are calling the function on the spot (executing your function).

On the other hand, writing it like this `test` will pass a pointer to the function that needs to be executed later (onChange in your case).